# Multiple Ajax Requests for creating Weather Forecast Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am building Weather Forecast Application and I am done with HTML and CSS coding, so in my application I have 6 different cities and I would like to output information about: Current Temperature, Icons for the current weather, Timezone and so on. Until now everything is working but I would like to learn how I can instead of making 6 different $.ajax GET requests to create only one for all of the 6 cities and take the information that I need from the output JSON objects. In my Weather Application I have HTML button which is allowing users to click and Change the current city.

I am using The Dark Sky Forecast API service and here is how I structure my GET request for one of my cities.

```
function getWeatherContent(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/02eb002028b663d6a8784ae534127171/35.685,139.7513889',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}

// Adding Information from our Ajax request.

getWeatherContent(function(details){
    console.log(details);

    // Take the current Temp from currently object and from Farenh transform it to Cels temp.
        var currentTemperature = details.currently['temperature'];

    // Calculate F to C by using JavaScript formula -> C = (F- 32) * (5/9).
    // Round the value to nearest integer.
        var celsFormula = Math.round((currentTemperature - 32) * (5/9));


    // Append Real-Time Degree to an HTML
        $('.degree').html('<p>' + celsFormula + '&deg;C' + '</p>');


});
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `async: false`? You seem to have this properly coded for asynchronous retrieval, so you shouldn't need that. As for minimizing the requests, I think you can only do that if `api.forecast.io` has some specific way of batching requests together with a longer URL. They might, but I don't know of it.

Comment: Yes, I would like async:false because I want the statement to finish it's execution before start the next one, api.forecast.io are very poor on documentation thats why I ask here. 

My point is what happen when I would like to take the parameters for the second city and because it is with different latitude and longitude I have to change my URL: https.... to be able to retrieve information and when I do I am going to lose the information for the previous city. So I want to find out a way to execute multiple lets say URL: Get request for 6 cities without losing information

Comment: `instead of making 6 different $.ajax GET requests to create only one for all of the 6 cities` - despite your claims of poor documentation, the documentation I see is quite complete and makes no mention of multiple locations in the one query. Just because an API doesn't do what **you** want it to do, doesn't make the documentation poor

Comment: Yes it's my fault I will try now. Thanks

Comment: there are better methods to "wait" for asynchronous operations to finish before beginning the next one ... `async:false` is a poor choice